# Как удалить значение переменной

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть массив из 4-ех элементов, я хотел сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку удалялось значение переменной которая идет после Состояние: , но у меня вылазит ошибка Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'splice')"

```js
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data() {
      return {
         cars: [
            {status: 'Идеальный', repair: 54541},
            {status: 'Плохой', repair: 5451},
            {status: 'Хороший', repair: 545},
            {status: 'Идеальний', repair: 5454},
         ],
      }
   },
   methods: {
   Clickrepaircar(index) {
         console.log(index);
         this.cars[index].staus.splice(index, 1)
      },
   },
});
```

```css
.footer__block {
   width: 337px;
   height: 58px;
   background: blue;
   border-radius: 24px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
   padding-left: 16px;
   padding-right: 8px;
}
.block__nomer {
cursor:pointer;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   width: 184px;
   height: 42px;
   border-radius: 17px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 700;
   font-size: 28px;
   line-height: 34px;
   letter-spacing: -0.05em; 
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="footer__block" v-for="(car, index) in cars">
     <div class="block-text">Состояние: {{car.status}}</div>
     <div class="block__nomer" @click="Clickrepaircar(index)">
        <div class="nomer__text">Ремонт - {{car.repair}}</div>
     </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что `this.cars[index].staus` во первых *staus* нет, есть *sta**t**us*, а вот вторых это не будет массивом и получите ошибку, что у status нет метода splice

Comment: Если я обращаюсь так, то удаляет полностью элемент 
this.cars.splice(this.cars[index].status, 1)

Comment: `this.cars.splice(index, 1)`

Comment: Оно удаляет элемент из массива, а я хотел бы , чтобы оно удаляло значение status, но к этому splice нельзя применить this.cars[index].status

Comment: `delete this.cars[index].status` - Если удалить ключ. `this.cars[index].status = null` - если значение